# Orientation issues when inserting jpeg image into pdf using fpdf

Tags: pdf, jpeg, fpdf

I have a folder with jpeg images inside. If I use the following to scan the folder and display the images everything appears as it should do:

```
//Gets an array of folder contents (excluding directories)
$files = array_filter(scandir($dir, 0), function($item) use ($dir) {
return !is_dir($dir . '/' . $item);
});

$count = sizeof($files);

if ($count > 0) {

    foreach ($files as $filename) {
        <img src="<?php echo "...path.../" . $filename; ?>" >
        <br> <?php                  
    }
} ?>
```

[image]

I then want to create a pdf document with these images inserted and I am using fpdf for this however there are issues with how the images are displayed in the pdf. If I create the pdf and view it on screen within the browser it looks fine, but if I download it and view the pdf on the PC in Acrobat the images are rotated:

[image]

So now I am looking at the image data using **exif_read_data** to understand what the issue is and have the following code when inserting the image into the pdf with fpdf:

```
$dir = getcwd();
$filename = $dir . ".. path ../" . $value;
$jpgFile = ".. path ../" . $value;
$newjpgFile = ".. path ../new" . $value;

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); //Read the image file into $img
$exif = exif_read_data($filename);

echo $exif['Orientation']; //For testing - this is printing 6 for both images so rotation needed

if ($img && $exif && isset($exif['Orientation'])) {
    
    $ort = $exif['Orientation'];

    if ($ort == 6 || $ort == 5)
        $newImg = imagerotate($img, 270, null);
    if ($ort == 3 || $ort == 4)
        $newImg = imagerotate($img, 180, null);
    if ($ort == 8 || $ort == 7)
        $newImg = imagerotate($img, 90, null);

    if ($ort == 5 || $ort == 4 || $ort == 7)
        imageflip($newImg, IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);
}

file_put_contents($newjpgFile, $newImg); //Meant to save new image but NO FILE SAVED
$pdf->Image($newjpgFile); //Puts into the pdf
```

The values 6 suggest that the images are actually landscape. If this is the case it leads me to my questions:

1. If images are orientaion 6 why does the < img src=" ...." > display portrait?
2. Why are the images displayed correctly in the pdf within browser but rotated when pdf downloaded?
3. Why is the file_put_contents line not working?

Comment: Do you have errors turned on which should give a clue as to why `file_put_contents` is failing? That said if it were failing the the last line of what you posted should also fail and result in an empty PDF. The viewport in the browser and in Adobe reader may affect how things are displayed. It is also helpful to tell `fPDF` more details about the image when including it.

Comment: Error reporting is on but I do not get any errors at the file_put_contents line. And ou are right - as things stand I do not get any output in the pdf. One thing I have tried is file_put_contents($newjpgFile, "Test") and a file is created in the correct folder so it must be something to do with $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename). If I try saving $img before any rotation and still nothing. Thanks

Comment: This won't show up in the comments well but I usually use [getimagesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to determine whether or not I need to flip a page if an image is rotated. `$iSize = getimagesize($image);  // get the size of the image to be added
        if ($iSize[1] > $iSize[0]) {  // image is 8x11
            $ourpdf->Image($image,5,null,206,0,'PNG');
        } else { // end of if image is 8x11
            $ourpdf->AddPage('L',[431.8,279.4]);
            $ourpdf->Image($image,null,null,421.8,249.3);
        }  // end of if image was NOT 8x11`

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. You should really fix the images when uploaded I'm told.

I wrote this at the top of my pdf making file. I've only tested it with portrait images.

```
function rotateImage($filePath){

  // the file must exist
  if(!file_exists($filePath)){die('image not found');}

  // if it was already processed return the already processed path
  if(file_exists('whatever/' . $filePath)){
    return 'whatever/' . $filePath;
  }

  // it must be a jpeg
  if(exif_imagetype($filePath) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG){
    $exif = exif_read_data($filePath);
    $degrees = 0;
    if (isset($exif['Orientation'])){
      switch ($exif['Orientation']){
        case 3: // Need to rotate 180 deg
          $degrees = 180;
          break;
        case 6: // Need to rotate 90 deg clockwise
          $degrees = 270;
          break;
        case 8: // Need to rotate 90 deg counter clockwise
          $degrees = 90;
          break;
      }
    }

    // rotate the image
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filePath);
    if($degrees != 0){
      $image = imagerotate($image, $degrees, 0);
    }

    // store the image
    imagejpeg($image,'whatever/'.$filePath);
    imagedestroy($image);
    return 'whatever/'.$filePath;
  }else{

    // if it is not a jpeg just return the path
    return $filePath;
  }
}
```

Replace /whatever/ with whatever your folder is to be called.

Use it like:

```
$this->Image(rotateImage('picture-of-mum.jpg'),0,0);
```

Enjoy